# When does the CFS schedule a new task?

Tags: scheduling

I am learning about operating systems by reading through "Three Easy Pieces", and I am stuck on the chapter about the Completely Fair Scheduler (Can be read [here](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/cpu-sched-lottery.pdf), p. 8-10). I understand that time slices are calculated dynamically per task based on its niceness/weight, that each task's runtime is tracked via the (also dynamically calculated) vruntime, and that when a context switch happens the task with the lowest current vruntime is selected to be scheduled next.

What I don't understand is when the OS decides to do a context switch. At some point the book states:

> Note that CFS utilizes a periodic timer interrupt, which means it can only make decisions at fixed time intervals. This interrupt goes off frequently (e.g., every 1 ms), giving CFS a chance to wake up and determine if the current job has reached the end of its run.

How does the OS determine the end of a task's run? Is it when the task's acutal runtime, since it has been scheduled, has reached its time slice value? Or when its virtual runtime since scheduling reaches the time slice? Or does the OS update the task's vruntime at each of these frequent interrupts and checks if there is another task with a lower one?

Answer (score 0):

> How does the OS determine the end of a task's run?

The authors are pretty direct about this point.

> does the OS update the task's vruntime at each of these frequent interrupts

Yes.
But to avoid doing expensive context switches too frequently,
it will typically let the current task keep running.

Earlier they gave the example of n = 4 processes running and
dividing a `sched_latency` of 48 msec by 4 gives
each a time slice of max(6, 12) equals 12 msec.
They explain:

> CFS then schedules the first job and runs it until it has used 12 ms
> of (virtual) runtime, and then checks to see if there is a job with lower vruntime to run instead.

So a dozen scheduler ticks find the first job running,
and only on the last tick does CFS evict it to schedule
another job.

> Is it when the task's actual runtime, since it has been scheduled, has reached its time slice value?

Actual runtime can be much less than one tick,
if for example the task starts running and
immediately gets stuck in a blocking read().
This is called voluntary pre-emption, and is
synchronous with the program logic rather
than happening when an asynchronous timer goes off.
So the read gets queued, and *then* the
scheduler does indeed go looking for a task
with low `vruntime` to run next.
But when an interrupt fires, the currently
running task is examined and is usually allowed
to keep running.